# Are all methods are preceded by a dot(.) or just some of them. How do we define it needs a dot or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods

I was learning Python by using Python Crash Course and came upon this String and Method thing: It only said that the dot(.) after name in `name.title()` tells Python to make the `title()` method act on the variable name.

Answer (score 2):

Not always, you can create a method dynamically:

```
from types import MethodType

def fn(x):
    return x.var

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 20

obj = A()

method_ = MethodType(fn, obj)
print(method_)
print(method_())
```

output :

```
<bound method fn of <__main__.A object at 0x000001C5E3F01FD0>>
20
```

A method is an instance of type `MethodType` and also it has an object bound to it, when method gets called, it's first parameter will always get filled with that object. Here `fn()` function's first parameter (x) will be filled with `obj` object.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is precise but i wanted to add to it.

Actually methods are functions that take objects as arguments and then return values based on that and as python is an Object Oriented Language therefore everything in python is an object.

When you call `name.title()`:
then, python search for the `title()` method for the `name` object.And as all methods are designated to take the object as an argument:

```
`def title(self):
    ...+
`
```

This is what a method definition look like inside a class and the `self` argument here stands for the object calling the method.
And we do not have to specify it explicitly it is recognised by the python interpreter.

As in your case: `name.title()` the object calling the method `title()` is the `name` variable therefore here `self` is assigned the value of `name` that is the function call `name.title()` is equivalent to `title(name)` but the former is the correct syntax of calling the method whereas the latter one is for comprehesion purpose.

If you run `title(name)` it surely gonna raise an error.
But, as the `title()` method belongs to the `str` class you can always call `str.title(name)`.

Hope i didn't confuse you instead of making it clearer...Happy coding..:)